# Chrome contenteditable set caret at beginning of text node not work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable element and want to set caret to at beginning of a text node.
See example please.
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/khiemnguyen/bw9xen5k/7)

```
<p id="p" contenteditable="true">Example: <i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b></p>

let range = new Range();

range.setStart(p.childNodes[2], 0);
range.setEnd(p.childNodes[2], 0);

// toString of a range returns its content as text, without tags
console.log(range); // Example: italic
range.collapse(false);
// apply this range for document selection (explained later below)
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
p.focus();
```

When I typing (on Chrome), caret always at the end of the i tag, but I want it must at beginning of text node.
That work on firefox but not on Chrome.
Thanks.

Comment: Changed all `childNodes[2]` -> `childNodes[1]` and got working. Is that what u wanted?

Comment: no, I mean the text after typing must be normarl text, but it is italic font in chrome.